# How to deploy a .Net Maui application to IPhone?

Tags: iphone, maui, maui-blazor

I am new to Net Maui development.
I have a developed one application so far and successfully created an apk bundle which I can copy and install on android devices WITHOUT deploying it to PlayStore.

Now I have some questions.

1. If I develop a blazor server side application which runs in a browser obviously it should work on all browsers on all platforms (without having to worry about deployment issues)? Just want to be sure about this from experts.
2. Similar would be the situation in case of a blazor hybrid application, except that it needs to be deployed on devices?
3. How do I deploy a Net Maui application to an iPhone without deploying it to App Store?

Answers to these from experts will help me resolve my confusion about which development platform to use.

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the link about how to [publish an iOS app for in-house distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-in-house?tabs=vs).

The process for creating an in-house distribution provisioning profile is as follows:

1. Create a distribution certificate. For more information, see Create
   a distribution certificate.
2. Create an App ID. For more information, see Create an App ID.
3. Create a provisioning profile. For more information, see Create a
   provisioning profile.